# Как вызвать cmd команды и записывать данные ответа от cmd?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, ip, ос

У меня вопрос: Как можно вызвать консольную команду и записать НЕ ВСЕ данные в консоль
пробовал через file.write os.system('ipconfig')` но не понял как можно в таком случае записать данные в переменную

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.system` для этой задачи не подойдет, используйте `subprocess`

Примерно так:

```
import subprocess

try:
    text = subprocess.check_output(
        ["ipconfig"],
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    ).decode('cp866')

except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    text = str(e)

print(text)
```

Comment: это вить работает не только с командой ip config?

Comment: @Kiber_kotleta, ага, просто вместо `"ipconfig"` передайте другую команду

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно просто сохранить вывод консоли в файл то можно использовать возможности консоли.

```py
os.system("ping ya.ru > ping.txt")
```

Сохранит в файл `ping.txt` в кодировки windows-866.

Если вывод нужно потом как то обработать в программе то вариант от gil9red функциональнее.